# What's the main problem of Windows-porting Banshee?

Tags: .net, mono, portability, banshee

Is it specific to the [Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/) project or to the Mono platform as a whole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not terribly current but [this blog post](http://abock.org/2008/10/20/cross-platform-thoughts-through-the-lense-of-banshee) mentions troubles with [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) as one major problem with getting Banshee to run on Windows. Other than that it seems that Banshee already compiles and runs on Windows for quite some time, but there just wasn't an official release (probably due to a lack of polish/bugfixes/release infrastructure).

Comment: The version I compiled could not find a player engine, thus it wouldn't actually play anything.  However, all the managed stuff like the GUI and such worked fine.  It looks like getting GStreamer working (the native code part) may indeed be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are getting your information from.

Banshee is a C# 3.0 app and according to [this page](http://banshee-project.org/download/development/), "XP, Vista, Server 2003, etc should all work.".

Comment: Still not officially released, which means it's not stable / functional (enough).

Comment: That's quite surprising, given that Songbird has been using GStreamer as their playback front-end for a while, I was hoping the fallout from their work windows work would improve the GStreamer port.

Perhaps it's just needs a maintainer to step up.